# How to use the experimental offscreenTab API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, offscreentabs

I've been searching for examples and reference and have come up with nothing. I found a note in offscreenTab source code mentioning it cannot be instantiated from a background page (it doesn't have a tab for the offscreenTab to relate to). Elsewhere I found mention that popup also has no tie to a tab.

How do you successfully create an offscreenTab in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`offscreenTabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html) won't function in a background page. Although not explicitly mentioned, the API cannot be used in a Content script either. Through a simple test, it seems that the popup has the same limitation as a background page.

The only leftover option is a tab which runs in the context of a Chrome extension. The easiest way to do that is by using the following code in the background/popup:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('ost.htm'), active:false});
// active:false, so that the window do not jump to the front
```

`ost.htm` is a helper page, which creates the tab:

```
chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create({url: '...'}, function(offscreenTab) {
    // Do something with  offscreenTab.id !
});
```

To change the URL, use [`chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html#method-update).

`offscreenTab.id` is a tabId, which ought to be used with the [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) API. However, at least in Chrome 20.0.1130.1, this is not the case. All methods of the `tabs` API do not recognise the returned tabID.

A work-around is to inject a content script using a [manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html), eg:

```
{"content_scripts": {"js":["contentscript.js"], "matches":["<all_urls>"]}}
// contentscript.js:
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ .. any request .. }, function(response) {
    // Do something with response.
});
```

Appendum to the background page:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Instead of checking for index == -1, you can also see if the ID matches
    // the ID of a previously created offscreenTab
    if (sender.tab && sender.tab.index === -1) {
        // index is negative if the tab is invisible
        // ... do something (logic) ...
        sendResponse( /* .. some response .. */ );
    }
});
```

With content scripts, you've got full access to a page's DOM. But not to the global object. You'll have to inject scripts (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)) if you want to run code in the context of the page.

Another API which might be useful is the [`chrome.webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) API. It can be used to modify headers/abort/redirect requests. Note: It cannot be used to read or modify the response.

Currently, the `offscreenTabs` API is experimental. To play with it, you have to enable the experimental APIs via `chrome://flags`, and add `"permissions":["experimental"]` to your manifest file. Once it's not experimental any more, use `"permissions":["offscreenTabs"]`.

Comment: Really helpful - I've got my offscreenTab working (generally except for the the fact the toDataUrl produces an image only 1 pixel high). I am using Chromium 20.0.1132.47 and I was able to access the offscreenTab by it's id that was passed. The work-arround you proposed (appendum to background) had problems with message details (sender was undefined). All in all, a superb answer of the highest caliber.

Comment: @Reinsbrain Someone else asked a question regarding taking a screenshot. I've investigated the issue, and posted an answer (including a [full demo](http://rob.lekensteyn.nl/offscreentabs.zip)) here: [How to produce an image by chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.toDataUrl correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11632292/938089?how-to-produce-an-image-by-chrome-experimental-offscreentabs-todataurl-correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that. I also had an image returning that was only 1-pixel height. Another subject that might be worth posing as a question: is there a way to evaluate (read) the DOM of the offscreenTab or is there only a screen capture of the page accessible?

Comment: @Reinsbrain Yes, that's possible. In my linked answer, I used a Content script to notify the background page using a simple `chrome.extension.sendMessage`. Within a Content Script, you've got full access to the DOM of the page, so you can read (and modify) it. If you need more details, feel free to post a new question.