# How to produce an image by chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.toDataUrl correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot, offscreentabs

I've got a problem: the `chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create` worked well, but the `toDataUrl` method produced an image with a height of 1 pixel. I've tried my best, but the image produced by `toDataUrl` does not show the size as I specified. How can this problem be solved?

Here is my code:

```
chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create({ url: "http:/www.baidu.com" }, function(offscreenTab) {
    // console.log(offscreenTab);
    chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.toDataUrl(offscreenTab.id, { format: "png" }, function(imgUrl) {
        $("#container").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to define the `width` and `height` properties when using [`chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html#method-create)?

Comment: Yes,I had tried to define the width and height ,but it did't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***The `offscreenTabs` API is experimental. The solution below has successfully been tested in Chromium 20.0.1132.57 (Linux), but that doesn't mean that the code still works in later versions.***
This answer is a follow-up to [How to use the experimental offscreenTab API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11361143/938089?how-to-use-the-experimental-offscreentab-api?)

---

The callback function of [`chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html#method-create) is called when the tab is created. Tests using the [`chrome.webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) API and the UNIX [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) command showed that the callback can be fired **before** the server responds. Hence, it's unlikely that a callback is triggered *after* the page is rendered.

My demo extension consists of 5 files. Their role is briefly explained:

- **`manifest.json`** - The required glue for the extension (see [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html)).
- **`sayhello.js`** - A [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) which notifies the background page. This helper is necessary, because the [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) and [`chrome.webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/chrome.webRequest.html) are useless: The event listeners of `chrome.tabs` are never triggered for offscreen tabs, and the event listeners of `chrome.webRequest` are triggered before the page is rendered.
- **`background.js`** - A background page to receive the [message](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) from the content script. [`chrome.extension.getViews()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) is used to locate the view which launches the offscreen tab.
- **`options.html`** - The **visible** view which launches offscreen tabs. (The background page cannot launch an offscreen tab).
- **`options.js`** - When manifest version 2 is active, inline scripts are not executed. The script must be placed in an external file, and loaded using `<script src>`.

I've uploaded the extension to http://rob.lekensteyn.nl/offscreentabs.zip <sup>same file, crx extension: [CRX](http://rob.lekensteyn.nl/offscreentabs.crx)</sup>. Don't forget to enable the **experimental** permission at `chrome://flags`, if you want to test it.

#### `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "OffscreenTabs API test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "offscreenTabs demo - See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11606135",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["experimental", "<all_urls>"],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["sayhello.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }]
}
```

#### `sayhello.js`

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage("Hello"); // Yup, that's it
```

#### `background.js`

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if (message === "Hello" && sender && sender.tab) {
        // Message received from content script, pass information to a view
        //  within our extension, which processes offscreenTabs
        chrome.extension.getViews({type:"tab"}).forEach(function(_window) {
            if (_window.checkTab) _window.checkTab(sender.tab.id);
        });
    }
});
```

#### `options.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<title>offscreenTabs test</title>
<script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Enter an URL and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.<br>
<input type="url" size="100" id="url" value="https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w">
<img id="lastImg">
</body>
</html>
```

#### `options.js`

```
"use strict";

var collection = [];
// This function is called by the background (via the content script)
// If the tabId is recognised, take a screenshot
function checkTab(tabId) {
    var index = collection.indexOf(tabId);
    if (index !== -1) {
        collection.splice(index, 1); // Remove tabId
        toDataUrl(tabId);            // Take screenshot
    }
}

function create(url, width, height) {
    var createProperties = {url: url};
    if (width) createProperties.width = width;
    if (height) createProperties.height = height;

    // Create offscreen tab
    chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.create(createProperties, function(offscreenTab) {
        console.log("Created " + offscreenTab.id, offscreenTab);
        collection.push(offscreenTab.id);
    });
}
function toDataUrl(offscreenTabId, options) {
    chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.toDataUrl(offscreenTabId, options, function(dataUrl) {
        document.getElementById('lastImg').src = dataUrl;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // "Press Enter to load the offscreen tab and take a screenshot"
    document.getElementById('url').onkeyup = function(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode == 13) 
            create(this.value);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much . You are so nice . Your method works well. Thank you again ！